# Async await for closure -> spinlock?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am maintaining a legacy code base which will use SwiftUI. I am using the new refreshable api: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/refreshable(action:). It is a bit annoying that they force you to use async await, since I have a part of refreshing code which can NOT be turned fully async await.

The reason I can not use async await for this code, is because the the application sends and receives messages over a *websocket*. The application manually matches the responses to the requests and than call the closure when they arrive. I don't believe this is possible to completely rewrite to async await.

I have a closure which eventually will always return a result. When that result have arrived, the spinner should go away. This is my horrible async await wrapper (simplified):

```
/// Terrible way of adding async await support
func sendAsync() async {
    try! await Task {
        var future: Void? = nil

        self.onReceive = { _ in
            future = ()
        }

        while true {
            if future != nil {
                return
            }

            // This is 10 ms
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000)
        }
    }.value
}
```

So this is a spinlock based async await wrapper. I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. I wrapped in inside a `Task`, it won't run on the main thread that way.

Is there some existing async await wrapper which waits for a value to be non-nil and then wakes up? Is there a different api for `refreshable` which does *not* require async await?

Comment: "The application manually matches the responses to the requests and than call the closure when they arrive. I don't believe this is possible to completely rewrite to async await." Maybe that should be your question? It sounds to me like it _is_ possible, using the usual unsafe continuation wrapper.

Comment: @matt I didn't knew about continuation, but I am currently using the withCheckedContinuation, which is awesome! I know have a startingpoint to really make it async await, thanks for the tip

Comment: Yep, `withCheckedContinuation`. Or, if you want, this smells a bit like an `AsyncSequence` (in which case you'd use `AsyncStream`).

Comment: WWDC 2021 video [Meet AsyncSequence](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10058/).

Comment: Except that you should change to `withUncheckedContinuation` before shipping.

Comment: @matt Why the unsafe variant? Is the checked variant a lot slower?

Comment: Yes, it is for debugging only. It has a lot of overhead that isn't needed if your implementation is correct.

Comment: If you are just learning Swift concurrency, stick with checked continuations. Avoid premature optimization: Don't use unsafe continuations unless you really need them. Sure, later, when you are performance tuning your optimized, release build (not debug builds) of an app and you find observable performance issues, then by all means consider unsafe continuations. But it is imprudent at this point, IMHO, as the overhead is minimal. In my benchmarking, the differences are measures in millionths of a second, so it is really not worth engaging with an unsafe API except in the most extreme cases.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the headsup, I will stick with the checked version

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in the comments, you can use [continuation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/checkedcontinuation) if the data you only received once:

```swift
func sendAsync() async {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        self.onReceive = { _ in
            continuation.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

or to receive a sequence of data use [`AsyncStream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream):

```swift
func sendAsync() -> AsyncStream<T> {
    return .init { continuation in
        self.onReceive = { value in
            continuation.yield(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Apple warns using continuations and resuming them multiple times, so use with extreme caution when using them:

> Resuming from a continuation more than once is undefined behavior. Never resuming leaves the task in a suspended state indefinitely, and leaks any associated resources. CheckedContinuation logs a message if either of these invariants is violated.